# Prove that $E[f(X)] \leq E[f(Z)]$,when $f(x)$ is a convex function,details as follow

Tags: probability

Recall that a function $f$ is said to be convex if, for any $x_1$, $x_2$ and for $ 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1
$,$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2) \leq \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda)f(x_2)$.

Let Z be a random variable that takes on a finite set of values in $[0, 1]$, and let
$p = E[Z]$. Define the Bernoulli random variable X by $Pr(X = 1) = p$ and $Pr(X =
0) = 1-p$.

1.Show that $E[f(Z)] \leq E[f(X)]$ for any convex function $f$.

2 Use the fact that $f(x) = e^{tx}$ is convex for any fixed $t \geq 0$ to obtain a Chernoff-like
bound for Z.

I cannot find a upper inequality to estimate the E[f(Z)], and have no idea of how to utilize the condition of convex function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof for part 1:

Suppose $Z$ takes the values $z_1,...,z_n$ with probabilities $p_1,...,p_n$, respectively.

Then we see that $$E[f(Z)] = \sum_1^n f(z_i)p_i = \sum_1^n f\big( (1-z_i)\cdot 0 + z_i \cdot 1\big) p_i$$$$\leq \sum_1^n \big((1-z_i)f(0)+z_if(1)\big)p_i = \big(1-\sum_1^np_iz_i \big)f(0)+\big(\sum_1^np_iz_i \big)f(1)$$$$=(1-E[Z])\;f(0)+E[Z]\;f(1)=E[f(X)]$$

Answer (score 0):

According to the fact of part 1,for any $t>0$ we have
\begin{equation}
E[e^{tZ}]\leq E[e^{tX}]
\end{equation}

So
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
Pr(Z \geq (1 + \delta)p) &=Pr(e^{tZ} \geq e^{(1 + \delta)p})\\
&\leq \frac{E[e^{tZ}]}{e^{(1 + \delta)p}}\\
&\leq \frac{E[e^{tX}]}{e^{(1 + \delta)p}}\\
&\leq \frac{e^{(e^t-1)p}}{e^{(1 + \delta)p}}
\end{split}
\end{align}

For any $\delta>0$,we can set $t = ln(1+\delta)>0$ to get:
$$Pr(Z \geq (1 + \delta)p)\leq (\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{(1+\delta)}})^{p}$$.

Similarly,for any $0<\delta<1$,we can set $t = ln(1-\delta)<0$ to get:
$$Pr(Z \geq (1 - \delta)p)\leq (\frac{e^{-\delta}}{(1-\delta)^{(1-\delta)}})^{p}$$